# Can one's professional degree (e.g. Masters, PhD, MD) be revoked on the basis of an academic offence committed during their undergraduate studies?

Tags: phd, plagiarism, bachelor

Title says all! I can't seem to find any answers pertaining to my question on google, and so I'm wondering if anyone here could share their thoughts/knowledge. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: @scaaahu This question is asking about actions taken long before the degree was awarded. What would happen if an earlier degree was revoked, and that degree was part of the admission application for the graduate degree?

Answer (score 2):

If the offense committed as an undergraduate was severe enough as to cause the undergraduate degree to be revoked, then it is possible to affect graduate enrollment under the guise of "fraudulent admission." (You shouldn't have been admitted because you knew you had committed an offense which would make you inadmissible, and therefore you are ineligible to enroll in the graduate program.)

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine that this may be theoretcally possible in some jurisdictions. I suspect that this is rare.

However, if you need legal advice, go get yourself a lawyer. Do not trust the advice of a random person on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the examination regulations.

**Some** examination regulations allow an awarded degree to be revoked in case of general misconduct, even if it is not related to the degree itself. It appears reasonable that such policy would also apply to a severe adacemic offense conducted during the undergraduate studies.

For the **other** examination regulation that do not include this policy, there is no legal basis for revoking the degree for an offense that is not related to the thesis.

Comment: What country / academic culture does this refer to?  In the US academic system, I don't know of any such thing as "examination regulations".

Comment: @NateEldredge: I'm guessing it's referring to Central Europe (German _Prüfungsordnungen_ = "examination regulations").